# Prove that $V_{\lambda_1}\subseteq \operatorname{ker}\rho$.

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I'm trying to prove the following theorem: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over an algebraically complete field and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ with minimal polynomial
$$m_T(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^d(x- \lambda_i)^{e_i}$$
Then

1. $V = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^d V_{\lambda_i}$.
2. Each $m_{T\restriction_{V_{\lambda_i}}}(x) = (x - \lambda_i)^{e_i}$.
3. Each $V_{\lambda_i}$ is invariant under $T$.

Here, $V_{\lambda_i}$ is the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_i$: $V_{\lambda_i} = \{\vec v \in V\mid (T- \lambda_i)^k\vec v = \vec 0\}$ for some positive integer $k$.

My proof attempt: We use induction on $d$. If $d = 1$, then for all $\vec v\in V$
$$(T- \lambda_1I)^{e_1}\vec v = m_T(T)\vec v = \vec 0$$
so $V = V_{\lambda_1}$ which proves (1). And (2) and (3) are clearly true.

Now let $d\geq 2$ and assume the conclusion holds for $d-1$. Since $(x- \lambda_1)^{e_1}$ and $\prod_{i = 2}^d(x - \lambda_i)^{e_i}$ are coprime, we can write
$$1 = \alpha(x)(x- \lambda_1)^{e_1} + \beta(x)\prod_{i = 2}^d(x - \lambda_i)^{e_i}$$
for some polynomials $\alpha, \beta$. Let $\rho = \alpha(T)(T - \lambda_1 I)^{e_1}$. Then $\rho^2 = \rho$ and $\rho$ commutes with $T$ so $V = \operatorname{ker}(\rho) \oplus \operatorname{im} (\rho)$ and both subspaces are invariant under $T$. Additionally, by a theorem I have proven previously, $m_{T\restriction_{\operatorname{ker}\rho}}(x) = (x - \lambda_1)^{e_1}$ and $m_{T\restriction_{\operatorname{im}\rho}}(x) = \prod_{i = 2}^d(x - \lambda_i)^{e_i}$. Now for $\vec v \in \operatorname{ker}\rho$,
$$(T- \lambda_1I)^{e_1}\vec v = m_{T\restriction_{\operatorname{ker}\rho}}(T\restriction_{\operatorname{ker}\rho})\vec v = \vec 0$$
so $\operatorname{ker}(\rho)\subseteq V_{\lambda_1}$. If I can show that $V_{\lambda_1}\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(\rho)$, then it will follow that $V_{\lambda_1}$ is invariant under $T$ and by applying the induction hypothesis to $T\restriction_{\operatorname{im}(\rho)}$, we get
$$V = V_{\lambda_1}\oplus \operatorname{im}(\rho) = V_{\lambda_1}\oplus \left(\bigoplus_{i = 2}^d V_{\lambda_i}\right) = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^d V_{\lambda_i}$$
which proves (1). And (2) and (3) similarly follow. My question is: how can I show that $V_{\lambda_1}\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(\rho)$?

I apologize if this is a stupid question. It seems like it should be obvious, but I can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: I think you can use the lemma: If the minimal polynomial $m_{T}(x)=f_1(x)\cdots f_d(x)$ where $f_1,\cdots,f_d$ are coprime, then $V=\mathrm{Ker}{f_1(T)}\oplus\cdots\oplus \mathrm{Ker}{f_d(T)}.$